# how can i change the arrow cursor image to hand image for my web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the image of my cursor,instead of it I want the hand image ,when I will take the cursor on the side bar menu than cursor image should be hand.

Comment: use css style="cursor:pointer"

Comment: would have been faster if you googled this.

Comment: How can you be so lazy?!

Answer (score 0):

**IN CSS**

```
#sidebar_menu { cursor: url('mycursor.cur'), pointer; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use Css

```
<div class="sidebar">
  bla bla
</div>
```

then in css file use :

```
.sidebar{
cursor:pointer;
}
```

or take this at all:

```
    <div style="cursor:pointer;">
      bla bla
    </div>
```

or if you want an image use this in css file :

```
.sidebar{
    cursor:url(/your_image_folder/your_hand_image.cur), pointer;
    }
```